# How do I collapse multiple rows that shares one identical value into a single row PRESTO SQL

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have this table

| id | cnt1 | cnt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7775 | 1 |  |
| 7775 |  | 2 |

I would like to combine the rows so that it comes out to this

| id | cnt1 | cnt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7775 | 1 | 2 |

I've tried a self join but it only appends the rows to the bottom. Any ideas? thank you!

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on required logic you can use `group by id` with corresponding [aggregate](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html) function, for example [`max`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max) (or `sum`), which will ignore null values.

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, cnt1, cnt2) AS (
    VALUES (7775, 1, null),
        (7775, null, 2)
) 

-- query
select id,
    max(cnt1) cnt1,
    max(cnt2) cnt2
from dataset
group by id
```

Output:

| id | cnt1 | cnt2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7775 | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

use `SubQuery` and `join` as follows

```
SELECT T1.Id,
       Cnt1,
       Cnt2
FROM   (SELECT Id,
               Cnt1
        FROM   Table
        WHERE  Cnt1 IS NOT NULL) T1
       JOIN (SELECT Id,
                    Cnt2
             FROM   Table
             WHERE  Cnt2 IS NOT NULL) T2
         ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```